# Datatables - combine ellipsis() and text() render function possible?

Tags: datatables

a column in datatables contains data that might look like html (greater / lesser than) characters. it also might contain data that is long in length.

to cut off the length I use the ellipsis option:

```
'render': $.fn.dataTable.render.ellipsis(20)
```

to avoid that the part of the data will be displayed as html I read I can use the text() option:

```
'render': DataTable.render.text()
```

but how can I combine the 2 render options?

```
$.fn.dataTable.render.text().ellipsis(20) does not work
```